# Infinite Loop while reading a file

Tags: java, infinite-loop, infinite

This is my piece of code where I am trying to read from a file. My file currently has 4 lines but code is not coming out of the loop after reading those lines.

```
    public class ViewServlet extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    doPost(request,response);
}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException{
    System.out.println("Logging in..");
    // retrieving values entered in form
    String uname = request.getParameter("uname");
    String pwd = (String) request.getParameter("pwd");

    if (uname.equals("admin") && pwd.equals("admin")) {

        try {
            viewDetails();
            System.out.println("Redirecting to view page..");
            response.sendRedirect("view.jsp");
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    } 
        }

public void viewDetails() throws Exception{
    System.out.println("Reading Data..");
    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("H:/Workspace/teamRecordsApp/WebContent/records.txt"));
    String record;
    String[] split =new String[5];

    ArrayList cuid = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList fname = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList lname = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList mobile = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList desk = new ArrayList();
    int count = 0;
    while((record=input.readLine()) != null){
        split = record.split(",");
        System.out.println("Record is : "+split[0]+","+split[1]+","+split[2]+","+split[3]+","+split[4]);
        cuid.add(split[0]);
        fname.add(split[1]);
        lname.add(split[2]);
        mobile.add(split[3]);
        desk.add(split[4]);
        count = count+1;

    }
    input.close();
    System.out.println("Reading Done...");
    Utils utils = new Utils();
    utils.setCuid(cuid);
    utils.setFname(fname);
    utils.setLname(lname);
    utils.setMobile(mobile);
    utils.setDesk(desk);
    utils.setCount(count);
    System.out.println("Total records : "+count);


}
```

}

*added whole servlet class now.

---

Console shows:

```
Logging in..
Reading Data..
Record is : 12,e,e,1234567890,1234
Record is : 12,e,e,1234567890,1234
Record is : 12,e,e,1234567890,1234
```

### Record is : 12,e,e,1234567890,123

After adding printStackTrace() in file,the exception I was getting is attached below. As said by @Pshemo, the last line which was empty was giving this exception. I was not able to figure this out by seeing the file and adding printStackTrace did the trick. Thanks a lot @Pshemo and others for helping!

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
at ViewServlet.viewDetails(ViewServlet.java:54)
at ViewServlet.doPost(ViewServlet.java:31)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Where is input defined and initialized?

Comment: What is it reading if it is not existing the loop? What do you see in the output?  Are you sure it is not reading another file?

Comment: I do not see anything in the console after I print the 4 records in the file. As after input.close() I have added a print command "Reading Done" to check if it coming out or not, which it is not printing.

Comment: Instead of adding more and more comments edit your question to reflect what you mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you invoke `viewDetails();` in try-catch block, but you don't handle exception (you don't even print its stack trace)

```
} catch (Exception e) {
    //nothing here... :/
}
```

I assume that exception was thrown inside your loop before `"Reading Done..."` massage. Exception could be caused by many things like if your file would have some empty line your loop you would read it `""` and to split it on `,` which would create one element array `{""}` and then by using `split[1]` you could get `IndexOutOfBoundException`. But that is just one of possibilities. To make sure what is wrong with your code add

```
e.printStackTrace();
```

to your `catch (Exception e)` block.